# Electron run on Nodejs. A JavaScript error occurred in the main process. Error spawn {path} Enoent

Tags: r, node.js, shiny, electron, spawn

I've made a Shinyapp, and try to turn it into a standalone application through Nodejs and Electron.
I've sucessfully made it on Windows. However, when I work on macOS, I encounter this error:
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception: Error: spawn {path of electron file} Enoent at ...[the error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiGBn.jpg)

Guess there's something wrong in Nodejs, but I'm a total newbie to nodejs. Have tried to add the file path into PATH environment variable, but it did not wrok. The same error appears.
Looking for someone who can help me sort it out.
I appreciate any help from you!!

Comment: Maybe you can post the source snippet of your js?  Obviously, paths on Windows and macOS are different.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi i am also facing same issue did you got any solution.